# Jasmine unit test spyOn not working in callback function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, ag-grid, spyon

I am using `ag-grid` and I need to write Jasmine unit test on a piece of code. This code calls our rest server using a class we called `RestService` and I want to use  `spyOn` to mock those calls and responses. In other places in the code I use `spyOn(RestService, 'function').and.returnValue()` and it works no problem at all. This code is automatically called by `ag-grid` and it is in a datasource object that has a `getRows` function in it. In here it calls the api to return the next page of data. The info can be found on https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/

```
var dataSource = {
    rowCount: null,
    getRows: function(params) {
        console.log("asking for " + params.startRow + " to " + params.endRow);
        // rest service call happens in here
        // something like params.context.mycontext.restService.fetchNextRows(data);
    }
}
```

I have a `spyOn` with `spyOn(restService, 'fetchNextRows').and.returnValue(Observable.of(something))` but it won't work for this. It tries to actually call the rest service and fails because that is not running during the unit test. Does anyone know a workaround?

my spec.ts uses:

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule(
 imports everything i use + has 
 providers: [RestService]
 ).compileComponents();

 let restService = TestBed.get("RestService");
 spyOn(restService, 'fetchNextRows').and.returnValue(Observable.of("mocked json"));

 fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ActionComponent);
 component = fixture.componentInstance;
```

Comment: How do you setup your test? Via TestBed? If so, this is probably because the service was not provided correctly

Comment: Yes I use TestBed. I configured this component the same way things are configured in app.module.ts. I import the RestService as a provider. The spyOn is working in like ngOnInit()  but once the ag-grid triggers the getRows() function to be called that one won't listen.

Comment: @Justin Cross: Can you possibly post some more code from your `.spec.ts` file?

Comment: I added some from my spec. Everything here is in my beforeEach() => {} .

Comment: could you also paste a code where dataSource is created? is it insode of ActionComponent onInit() ?

Comment: I had it where you create all the variables for the component. But even changing that to dataSource: any;        and then creating it in the ngOnInit function like this.dataSource = { code here } gives the same result for my unit test.

Answer (score 0):

In your `spec.ts`, you must not use double quotes when requesting the `RestService` from the `TestBed`.

```
let restService = TestBed.get(RestService);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I have found a solution, I still don't know why spyOn won't work in these cases with the getRows function.

Instead of using spyOn, create a spy object and provide it instead of the actual service.

Before `TestBed.configureTestingModule(...)` in your *.spec.ts*, add this:

```
let restServiceStub = jasmine.createSpyObj('RestService', ['fetchNextRows']);
restServiceStub.fetchNextRows.and.returnValue(Observable.of("mocked JSON"));
```

Now, provide it to your test configuration instead of the actual service:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule(
    imports everything i use + has 
    providers: [{
        provide: RestService,
        useValue: restServiceStub
    }]
).compileComponents();
```

I'm using this for my AgGrid server side tables and it works. Still, I don't understand why the spyOn on the service `spyOn(RestService, 'fetchNextRows').and.returnValue(Observable.of("mocked JSON")` works for all calls except those made by AgGrid.